# sql one to many relationship and working with foreign keys

Tags: sql

i have 2 tables artist and employee as
artist(artistId,name,contact,address,employeeId) and
employee(employeeId,name,contact,email)
here artistId and employeeId are primary key and set to auto increment. 
I want to insert data into artist table but artist can not insert employee Id.So how it will get assigned to artist? what should I write?
i have written following query in stored procedure without employee id:
insert into artist(name,contact,address)values(@name,@contact,@address).

Please help.

Comment: Is this a one to many relationship or an inheritance relationship? Is the artist the employee also? Just trying to clarify?

Comment: Depends on which flavor of SQL you are using, exactly what you can do. Also, it depends on if you are actually enforcing a foreign key constraint.

Comment: actually it is given that employee should get assigned to each artist.and relationship between them is one employee verifies many artists.I am new to sql. So i am confused

Comment: Sounds like you should have an employee (employeeId) already available for each artist as you insert the artist. If not you just backfill the artist.employeeId later with an update.

Comment: "I want to insert data into artist table but artist can not insert employee Id." Do you have employeeId declared as "autoincrement" in both tables?

Comment: auto increment of employeeId is set only in employee table..Should i set it in artist also?

Comment: yes employeeId should be from already available ids from employeeId table

Comment: 1. No it should not be set in artist--just wanted to make sure it wasn't. 2. If it is already available you cna provide it in the insert--just add employeeif and @employeeid to your insert fields and values lists.

Comment: if i write like this: insert into artist(name,contact,address,employeeId)values(@name,@contact,@address,@employeeId).It will solve my problem?

Comment: Just a quick note, if you are enforcing Foreign keys you need the employeeId to be a valid employee pre-existent in the employee table before you insert into artist.

Comment: if you provide the correct @values then it should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Moving from question comments to an answer.

Since you already have the employee you can simple include the employeeid in the insert.

```
insert into artist
  (name,contact,address,employeeId)
values
  (@name,@contact,@address,@employeeI‌​d)
```